# How to make the text inside a specific cell of a table bold in PDF using Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm creating a PDF document and inside of it i'm creating a table.
I want some cells to have bold text style.
How can this be done?
I Have below code every thing working fine. But cell text not Bold in the cell

```
Document document = new Document();
document.open();
final String[][] DATA = {{"NAME", "SUDARSAN"},{"RoLL No", "2001"}};
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
Paragraph paragraph=new Paragraph(DATA[0][1]); paragraph.getFont().setStyle(Font.BOLD);
table.addCell(paragraph);
document.close();
```

Comment: Please put the code in your question

Comment: @whackamadoodle, There is a problem in text area I can not putted my code...I don't know proper valid writing process in question text area.

Comment: Edit your question and put your code inside of ``. It will look like `this`

Comment: @whackamadoodle , Done

Comment: @Thanks all ,code  is paragraph.getFont().setSize(20); working fine

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
private static final Font BOLDFont = new Font(Font.getFamily("TIMES_ROMAN"),12,Font.BOLD);

Paragraph p = new Paragraph("'Bold Text",
                BOLDFont );
```